# Am I doing my UML diagram correctly?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, staruml

So as mentioned this a Homework question so please go easy on me.
basically I've got to create a use-case diagram for TWO sub-systems. I've got the jist of it however I cannot differentiate the two and am sort of confused on how they are meant to be interlinked.

Documentation:

```
 Manufacturing

Factory Operation
Each internal factory organises itself into manufacturing modules. Each module has a module leader and a number of technicians. Many internal factories can make the same part.  A part may be made up of other parts in which it is called an assembly. Each part has unique part number and a CAD/CAM drawing which is stored electronically. The drawing holds details such as issue number, sizes, materials and sub parts if it is an assembly.  The manufacturing system holds a manufacturing route for each part.  This details how the part should be made on the CNC machine in terms of manufacturing process (for instance lathe -2 hours, mill -3 hours, grind -1 hour , broach -1 hour, drill -1 hour, hardening - 1 hour, annealing -1 hour , plating - 0.5 hour).   A schedule has to be set up by the module leader which states on a weekly basis what CNC machines will be used and who will use them, broken down by the hour.  The module leader does this by looking at all the orders received at the beginning of the week and also considering any orders anticipated and the deadlines that have to be met.  Changes sometimes need to be made to the schedule to cope with unexpected staff absence, delays or machine break down. The module leader has to forecast the raw materials (e.g.  a bar of steel) needed to be bought in the make the parts  on a daily basis. Orders for raw materials are to  a single specialist supplier.  The module leader uses forecasts,  bill of materials and part manufacturing specifications to work  out what raw materials are needed. Daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly and annual plans are made for raw materials.

Traceability
Traceability of components is very important in the aircraft industry.  If a part fails     when in use, it is returned to the factory for a diagnosis.  If the factory finds a fault in a component it must trace that component back to its original batch and perhaps recall all parts in the same batch.  Every bar of metal has a batch number set by the supplier. If a technician makes a part from that bar of metal the bar’s batch number must be maintained for traceability. Parts also have a batch number.  This is different to the batch number of the metal bars.  The batch number of the metal bars are set by the supplier of the metal. The batch number of the parts are set by the factory. If a number of parts are made in one manufacturing run (which might involve a number of processes) they belong to the same batch.  Typically the factory will receive an order for a number of parts and will keep all those parts in the same batch.  This is to ensure good traceability from when the part fails in the air right back to the bar of metal that was used to make it. The part batch number is assigned when parts come off the manufacturing process and into store.

Stores
Each factory has a store for finished goods. When parts leave manufacturing they must be booked into store.  When parts leave store they must be booked out.  The store has a number of containers to hold the parts. The store needs to record where the parts are held ( i.e. container number).  Stores are responsible for despatching parts.
```

Sorry it isn't formatted well, I am not sure on how to do so.

Task:

```
**Manufacturing ( Bill of Materials and Manufacturing Method)**
Bill of Materials (how assemblies are composed),  
Manufacturing for each part (how each part must be manufactured)

**Manufacturing (Scheduling and Traceability)**
Machine Shop Scheduling (who is using which machine and when)
Traceability (Batch numbers, linking to orders, booking into store when complete)
Factory stores
```

use-case diagrams so far:

[enter link description here](http://i46.tinypic.com/zv1lza.jpg)

[enter link description here](http://i46.tinypic.com/990y0l.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uml does not have a notion of correctness. [According to this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009828), the uml is in a word, "correct",  if it conveys the idea you with to get across.

Here are some suggestions I would to better convey the idea, others may disagree:
Receive faulty part should [be an extension of](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009828) receive part.
Who is the store user?
Who is the module leader? Could you be more specific?
Are book parts and record parts similar enough to be combined?
Does hold part depend on anything like say "Order part"
Is "set batch number" optional of make part? If so, extends is fine, however if setting the batch number is a required step to making the part, then make part should "use" or "include" set batch.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've gone ahead and bought the book and will use it to reference in the future.